# Running multiple versions of Internet Explorer on one machine safely

Tags: internet-explorer

I have heard of MultipleIE and IETester - but I believe this may be unsafe for the machine. I wanted to know if this was unsafe and if so what is the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't heard of MultipleIE, but IETester is a standalone program that runs different versions of IE's display and Javascript engines in different tabs, and it is completely safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to IE10 (you can do this on Windows 7). IE10 has a developer tools to test versions down to IE7.

Try here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-10-worldwide-languages

Comment: Good answer, very descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to running multiple versions of Internet Explorer on one machine safely to [IE Collection](https://utilu.com/IECollection/).